# pip ignores pyproject.toml

Tags: python, pip, pyproject.toml

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["wheel", "setuptools>=18.0", "cython>=0.29.0", "numpy>=1.20"]
```

I package via `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`, then `twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*`, and

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ mypkg==0.1.0
```

into a fresh virtual Anaconda environment, which starts installing `numpy-1.9.3` that's clearly below `1.20`, and yields

```
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 328, in msvc14_gen_lib_options
        if LegacyVersion(np.__version__) < LegacyVersion('1.11.2'):
    AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '__version__'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

My `setup.py` doesn't have `setup_requires`, but does have `include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]`, and `ext_modules=Cython.Build.cythonize(setuptools.Extension(...))`. Windows 10.

Why is the requirement being ignored, and how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyproject.toml` is for `pip install .` rather than `python setup.py` or `pip install uploaded_pkg`. It wasn't ignored, the requirement was already satisfied in the virtual environment.

`install_requires=["numpy>=1.20.0"]` is what's needed for `pip install uploaded_pkg`.